# Python For loops with while and if statements: Why doesnt it return in the first case?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

Hey guys I know this question might seem dumb, but I just started. This is Python 3.7.
Any way I have written 2 versions of the code, the second one works, but I've added another while loop where I thought it wasn't needed. Why doesn't the first version work? Its iterating a list of numbers (nums).

This is from a problem statement:
*Write a function that takes in a list of integers and returns True if it contains 007 in order.*

- spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5]) --> True
- spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7]) --> True
- spy_game([1,7,2,0,4,5,0]) --> False

My first code was this, and it always returned False:

```
z = 0

for i in nums:
    while z < 2:
        if i != 0:
            break
        else:
            z += 1
            break
    if i != 7:
        break
    else:
        return True

return False
```

---

Why does this change, make it work?

```
z = 0

for i in nums:
    while z < 2:
        if i != 0:
            break
        else:
            z += 1
            break
    while not z < 2:
        if i != 7:
            break
        else:
            return True

return False
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: This would also return true for a list such as `[1, 0, 3, 0, 7]`. And since you're iterating over the list, you don't need `while` statements at all - it's just `while` on each value, which is odd, and I _think_ you'll also get a match on just  `[0, 7]`, since the while loop is going to increment z to 2 as soon as it hits a zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the way you're using the while-loop. The code in the while-loop is executed as long as the condition is met. However, you call a break or return inside the while-loop in each way. 
So what you actually want to use is an if-statement instead of the while-loop. Then the break would work the way you expected it to work in the first example. The break makes the program jump out of the current loop, that is the while-loop. But for the first example to work correctly, it should jump out of the higher for-loop. Using if instead of while should fix this.

Maybe try something like this:

```
z = 0

for i in nums:
   if z < 2:
      if i == 0:
         z += 1
   else:
      if i == 7:
         return True

return False
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply. Your solution is much better. You also got me thinking and yes, I was making a big mistake. Bear in mind im new at this: The 1st case was always returning False because, I was treating the IF as a loop. I thought that with the break after the IF i !=7, it would break from the IF and return to the FOR.. I just realized that the break, was breaking the FOR loop, thus returning the False at the bottom. Thats why in the 2nd example it did work because the break was breaking the second WHILE loop.. Anyway, thanks again, you've helped me out a lot.